# Blocking/Long-Running Phoenix Requets

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am making a call to a Phoenix route whose work tends to take 10+ seconds.  This is too long and Phoenix times out.

This problem could be solved by websockets easily, however I would like to know how it's done with plain REST.

And what is the Phoenix process model?  Do all requests go to a worker pool, it's just that it would be unwise to block for long even with the pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something else that you could try perhaps: Fire up a process to do the heavy lifting and return immediately to the client. Assign a name or otherwise make this task discoverable. Then poll from the client every so often to check whether the process is finished. Once its finished and you get the result back you can kill it.

The polling is a workaround only if you really cant use sockets, socket push would be much more efficient otherwise

EDIT:
Ok, this is a proof of concept which should point you in the right direction.

First define a module to encapsulate this behaviour

```
defmodule LongRunningTask do
  def start(params) do
    spawn(fn -> 
      me = self()
      spawn(fn -> do_long_running_task(me, params) end)
      wait()
    end)
    |> inspect()
  end

  def get_result("#PID" <> ref) do
    pid = ref
    |> :erlang.binary_to_list
    |> :erlang.list_to_pid
    send(pid, {:is_it_done_yet?, self()})
    receive do
      {:answer, result} -> result
      :still_not_done -> :still_not_done
    after
      1000 -> :no_one_here
    end
  end

  defp wait(state \\ nil) do
    receive do
      {:result, result} -> wait(result)
      {:is_it_done_yet?, from} ->
        case state do
          nil ->
            send(from, :still_not_done)
            wait(state)
          result ->
            send(from, {:answer, result})
        end
    end
  end

  defp do_long_running_task(pid, _params) do
    Process.sleep(10_000)
    send(pid, {:result, "the answer"})
  end
end
```

Then in your controller define 2 actions, the initial request that fires off the task and a polling endpoint where you can check for the completion

```
defmodule MyController do  
  def init_request(conn, params) do
    ref = LongRunningTask.start(params)
    json conn, %{ref: ref}
  end

  def poll(conn, %{"ref" => ref}) do
    case LongRunningTask.get_result(ref) do
      :still_not_done -> json conn, %{result: "nope, poll again"}
      result -> json conn, %{result: result}
    end
  end  
end
```

PS: Elixir is fun :)

Comment: That is half a solution, one that I was hoping for, however the difficulty is how to get a reference to the actual HTTP request.  It doesn't seem possible without still running into the same timeout problem.

Comment: @Bryan I've updated with sample code. It should go without saying that this is NOT production ready code, it's just a proof of concept to help flesh out the idea. In a production setting the long running processes would be supervised or monitored to always know their fate. Also if these long running tasks are user specific and/or contain sensitive data the #PID<1.2.3> exchanging scheme is EXTREMELY unsecure, as anyone could construct a random pid and check your app state, you should probably encrypt them and/or use another method to produce refs that are tied to the current user only

Comment: I'm using genserver + poolboy for the task - your second code bit enlightened me.  Will definitely use sockets but wanted to know the alternative here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know how it's done with plain REST

You either increase the efficiency of your code, increase the timeout on the webserver, or some combination of both.

> What is the Phoenix process model? Do all requests go to a worker pool

No, the requests do not go into a worker pool.

For a web server, Phoenix is currently using [cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy). So when you hit a Phoenix Endpoint, it is actually hitting the underlying cowboy implementation, which will spawn a new Erlang process for your request. Then it is up to the Erlang scheduler to actually give your process CPU time.

Comment: The long running request does not (significantly) slow down other requests via the beam (erlang virtual machine). However, it might do so through your database or other external components. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: Who is it that is timing out, Phoenix or Cowboy?  If Phoenix then is it possible to place that HTTP request on hold, do the work in some pool, and when result is ready simply send to the PID 'holding' the HTTP request?

Comment: I guess the common solution, beyond websockets, would be client polling server until long running task completes.